# Additional custom button to change product price before adding to cart in Wovcommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, custom-fields, price

In Woocommerce, I have add an extra price field **`"bestprice"`** for my products in backend.

So now I have as possible price settings:

- regular price (for example **`100$`**),
- sale price, (not set)
- *(and)* the `bestprice` (for example **`90$`**)

I would like to add a button **"click for better price"** in product page. Normally the price in product page will be **the regular price**.

- If user press add to cart, 1 product of **`100$`** will be added in the cart.
- If user click on "click for better price" button (the price will be changed to **`bestprice`** **90$**) and when he will press add to cart the product of **`90$`** will be added in cart.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution code… I have replaced your custom field slug with `_bestprice` as it should start with an underscore like `_price` or `_sale_price`.

In backend for simple products, the additional "Best price" custom field:

[image]

```
// Add a custom field to product in backend (for testing)
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_field_product_options_pricing' );
function add_field_product_options_pricing() {
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_bestprice',
        'label'         => __('Best price', 'woocommerce') . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
        'placeholder'   => __('Set the best price…', 'woocommerce'),
        'description'   => __('Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
    ));
    echo '</div>';
}

// Save product custom field to database when submitted in Backend (for testing)
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_options_custom_fields', 30, 1 );
function save_product_options_custom_fields( $post_id ){
    // Saving custom field value
    if( isset( $_POST['_bestprice'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_bestprice', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_bestprice'] ) );
    }
}
```

In single product page we add a custom button *(and a hidden field)*:

[image]

When customer hit "Get better price button", the displayed price change in a kind of price range just like when the product is on sale *(When product is on sale, it replace the sale price)*:

[image]

Here (example) the product is on sale, the sale price `$32.00` is replaced by the bestprice `$30.00`.

```
// Add a 'Get better price' additional button and a hidden field below single add to cart button
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'before_add_to_cart_button' );
function before_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    // Get your product 'bestpprice' custom field
    $bestprice = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_bestprice', true);

    if( ! empty($bestprice) ):

    $bestprice = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $bestprice ) );
    $reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
    $range = wc_format_sale_price( $reg_price, $bestprice );
    ?>
    <!-- The button and hidden field --> 
    <div class="bestprice-wrapper"><br>
        <a href="" class="get_bestprice button alt" id="get_bestprice"><?php _e('Get better price'); ?></a>
        <input type="hidden" name="bestprice" id="bestprice" class="bestprice" value="" />
    </div>
    <!-- The jQuery code --> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            var b = '<?php echo $bestprice; ?>',
                i = 'input[name=bestprice]',
                p = 'p.price',
                r = '<?php echo $range; ?>',
                t = 'a#get_bestprice'
                u = true;
            $(t).click( function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if(u){
                    $(p).html(r);  // Replacing price with the range
                    $(i).val(b);  // Set the best price in hidden input field
                    u = false;   // Disable button
                    $(t).text('Better Price active'); // change button text
                    $(t).removeClass('alt'); // Remove button 'alt' class for styling
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

The data is added to cart object and change the cart item price when "bestprice" has been enabled:

[image]

```
// Add custom fields data to cart items
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'custom_add_cart_item_data', 20, 2 );
function custom_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

    if( ! isset( $_POST['bestprice'] ) )
        return $cart_item;

    if( ! empty( $_POST['bestprice'] ) )
        $cart_item['custom_data']['bestprice'] =  (float) esc_attr( $_POST['bestprice'] );

    return $cart_item;
}

// Replacing cart item price with 'bestprice'
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cart_item_bestprice', 20, 1 );
function set_cart_item_bestprice( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['bestprice'] ) ){
            // Set the calculated item price (if there is one)
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['bestprice'] );
        }
    }
}
```

This is an optional code **to Change add to cart link by a link to the product** in Shop and archives pages when **bestprice** is set in the product setting options:

```
// Change add to cart link by a link to the product in Shop and archives pages for bestprice enabled option
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'bestprice_loop_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function bestprice_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {

    // Get your product 'bestpprice' custom field
    $bestprice = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_bestprice', true);

    // Only for enabled "bestprice" option price.
    if( ! empty( $bestprice ) ){
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

> *Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.